# How can we pass user information to restrict the swagger APIs endpoints

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

We have use case where we need show user credential params such as username and password and based on user name value and password validation on backend side we have to render swagger APIs.
Not able to figure out how i can render swagger APIs based on result of authentication result.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of swagger you are using, but it looks like there is support for protecting endpoints via some kind of authentication using Swagger 2.0 and 3.0.

From the [2.0 docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/):

> Swagger 2.0 lets you define the following authentication types for an API:
>
> Basic authentication
>      API key (as a header or a query string parameter)
>      OAuth 2 common flows (authorization code, implicit, resource owner password credentials, client credentials)

From the [3.0 docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/):

> OpenAPI uses the term security scheme for authentication and authorization schemes. OpenAPI 3.0 lets you describe APIs protected using the following security schemes:
>
> HTTP authentication schemes (they use the Authorization header):
>           Basic
>           Bearer
>           other HTTP schemes as defined by RFC 7235 and HTTP Authentication Scheme Registry
>       API keys in headers, query string or cookies
>           Cookie authentication
>       OAuth 2
>       OpenID Connect Discovery

Each of those sets of documents has links to examples and further documentation.

Comment: I am using letest swagger ui code. based on user credentials my swagger defination will change and it wil have restricted end points.

Comment: Ah, so you are looking to show different API content based on who ai accessing the API?